# Internet disconnects at the router and only when I'm online

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, router

My Internet occasionally drops out for my whole house when I'm on it, this doesn't happen when anyone else in my house is on the Internet, so this might be a problem with Ubuntu causing the Internet to drop out at the router? Any idea what this is?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a ThinkPad T430 and the router is a DrayTek Vigor2760. The Internet provider is PlusNet and the house is in Buckinghamshire, UK.

```
$ journalctl --unit=NetworkManager
Jun 25 20:26:57 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954817.8435] sup-iface[0x55d3dcc67240,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jun 25 20:26:57 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954817.8757] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun 25 20:26:57 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954817.9463] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.4532] device (wlp3s0): link timed out.
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.4561] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.4726] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Belkin54g 1'
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.4743] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.4756] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.5115] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 24770
Jun 25 20:27:13 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954833.5115] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun 25 20:27:17 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954837.2648] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4342] policy: auto-activating connection 'Belkin54g 1'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4356] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Belkin54g 1' (a57eefba-4c40-4625-b592
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4360] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state:
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4362] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4370] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'mana
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4375] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Belkin54g 1' has security, but secret
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4376] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'ma
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4377] sup-iface[0x55d3dcc67240,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4425] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'm
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4474] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'mana
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4481] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Belkin54g 1' has security, and secrets 
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4481] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Belkin54g'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4482] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4482] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4482] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4482] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4482] Config: added 'psk' value ''
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4739] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.4892] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5014] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5014] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connec
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5015] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'ma
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5024] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5060] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 26537
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 dhclient[26537]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.11 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7ff27e80)
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 dhclient[26537]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.11 from 192.168.1.1
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5908] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 192.168.1.11
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5908] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5909] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5909] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 604800
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5909] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5909] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '8.8.4.4'
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5909] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5946] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: '
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5957] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state:
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5960] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.5962] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.6150] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.6151] policy: set 'Belkin54g 1' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529954840.6157] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 25 20:27:20 adam-thinkpad-t430 dhclient[26537]: bound to 192.168.1.11 -- renewal in 291393 seconds.
Jun 25 20:30:27 adam-thinkpad-t430 NetworkManager[3061]:   [1529955027.6802] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Comment: Where does your router send its logs? Where is your router managed from? What do your logs say? `journalctl --follow` in a terminal window will show all the latest log messages. `journalctl  --unit=NetworkManager` will show logs from NetworkManager.

Comment: Ah yes I'll use `journalctl` next time it cuts out, great idea thank you, I for one really appreciate how systemd centralizes logs!

Comment: @waltinator Added the journalctl log, does that help? :)

Comment: not so much - start your log dump several minutes earlier, or, use `journalctl --unit=NetworkManager`. It does say "` reason=4 locally_generated=1`".

Comment: @waltinatorE edit the dump to the NM one, there's nothing earlier than that that's relevant (not from NetworkManager)